# Can I only extract the same value from two tables?

Tags: arrays, lua, compare, intersection

What is the best way, in terms of code cleanness or efficiency, to find an "intersection" of two Lua numbered tables, i.e. a table that contains only values that are present in both tables?

For example, I have

```lua
a={1,2,3,4,5}
b={3,4,5,6,7}
```

Since 3, 4 and 5 are found in both `a` and `b`, I want `{3,4,5}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a slightly different approach, based on *sets*. The performance will not necessarily improve, bit the code will be clean, understandable and expandable.

In Lua a set can be easily implemented as a table, where the keys are set items and the values are `true`, therefore, to check whether an item is present in the set, you just need `if set[item] then`.

I will give three variants of the code. The first cleanly implements an intersect operator but then has to transform the resulting set back to an indexed Lua table. The second immediately returns the intersections of two sets as an array. The third is a compromise between the first two.

Note that neither contains nested loops over `a` and `b`: it's *O(a + b)* rather than *O(ab)*.

First:

```lua
local insert, sort = table.insert, table.sort -- localise for performance.

local a = {1,2,3,4,5}
local b = {3,4,5,6,7}

local function toset (tbl)
    local set = {}
    for _, value in ipairs (tbl) do
        set [value] = true
    end
    return set
end

local function intersect (set1, set2)
    local intersection = {}
    for item, _ in pairs (set1) do
        if set2 [item] then
            intersection [item] = true
        end
    end
    return intersection
end

local function toarray (set)
    local array = {}
    for item, _ in pairs (set) do
        insert (array, item)
    end
    sort (array)    -- since you want {3,4,5} not {4,5,3}
    return array
end

-- Fortunately, table.concat does not require previous tostring:
print ('{' .. table.concat (toarray (intersect (toset (a), toset (b))), ', ') .. '}')
```

Second:

```lua
local insert, sort = table.insert, table.sort -- localise for performance.

local a = {1,2,3,4,5}
local b = {3,4,5,6,7}

local function toset (tbl)
    local set = {}
    for _, value in ipairs (tbl) do
        set [value] = true
    end
    return set
end

local function intersect_and_to_array (set1, set2)
    local array = {}
    for item, _ in pairs (set1) do
        if set2 [item] then
            insert (array, item)
        end
    end
    sort (array)    -- since you want {3,4,5} not {4,5,3}
    return array
end

-- Fortunately, table.concat does not require previous tostring:
print ('{' .. table.concat (intersect_and_to_array (toset (a), toset (b)), ', ') .. '}')
```

Third:

```lua
local insert = table.insert -- localise for performance.

local a = {1,2,3,4,5}
local b = {3,4,5,6,7}

local function toset (tbl)
    local set = {}
    for _, value in ipairs (tbl) do
        set [value] = true
    end
    return set
end

local function filter_array_through_set (array, set)
    local filtered = {}
    for _, value in ipairs (array) do
        if set [value] then
            insert (filtered, value)
        end
    end
    return filtered -- the order of array is preserved.
end

-- Fortunately, table.concat does not require previous tostring:
print ('{' .. table.concat (filter_array_through_set (a, toset (b)), ', ') .. '}')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the first question in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `iterate` on one of the table and `output the value` if you find it in the other table. On, my computer the following code returns {3, 4, 5}, it basically implement the `intersection of 2 sets`.

```
a={1,2,3,4,5}
b={3,4,5,6,7}

function Contains (Array, Item)

  local Found = false
  local Index = 1

  while ((not Found) and (Index <= #Array)) do
    if Array[Index] == Item then
      Found = true
    else
      Index = Index + 1
    end
  end

  return Found  
end

function Intersects (Ta, Tb)

  local Result = { }
  local Index

  for Index = 1, #Tb do
    if Contains(Ta, Tb[Index]) then
      Result[#Result + 1] = Tb[Index]
    end
  end

  return Result
end

Result = Intersects(a, b)

-- Print the results
local Index, Value

for Index, Value in ipairs(Result) do
  print(Value)
end
```